# Terminated for too many mistakes on the first month

Tags: work-environment, termination

I landed in my new job that required ten years of experience, and where I realised it was too informal.

My last environment was open and encouraged asking questions, and people from different hierarchical levels were more than happy to provide answers for the sake of the success of the project.

This new job, however, was the complete opposite. Asking questions was deprecated, there was no documentation, no manuals, and I didn't beneficiate from any training.

I started working on real tasks on my second week already. Except that, I had to deploy my work directly in production without prior verification from older colleagues or such.

I was not sure this was the right thing to do, but my boss was giving direct unquestionable orders.

I was uncomfortably executing her orders.

Indeed, production was impacted and work had to be interrupted until we fix the small hidden mistakes.

This happened 3, 4 or five times and I could feel that my boss was more and more disappointed.

She made her mind of the 35th day to terminate me, and waited till the end of probation to show her discontent.

Do I deserve to be terminated or do my boss has a part of responsibility on this?

Comment: First off, sorry to hear you were let go.  Unfortunately whether you "deserve" to be terminated is not a question that we can answer.  From your description, it certainly doesn't sound like the job was a good fit for you nor a position that you liked so it seems reasonable to part ways after the probation period.  Probation is supposed to be a two-way street where you see whether the position is a good fit for you while the company sees whether you are a good fit for them.  It doesn't sound like either side was happy with the way things were going.

Comment: Chin up, sounds like terrible management, hope you find something better soon.

Comment: *"I had to deploy my work directly in production"* *"work had to be interrupted until we fix the small hidden mistakes."* Could you please elaborate on this? Did you perform at least some basic testing before releasing your work? Are you sure the mistakes were "small" enough and couldn't have been caught before release? Generally release to production is not halted to fix "small" mistakes, it is only done for major problems.

Answer (score 7):

What kind of management lets someone who's put four showstoppers into production in his first five weeks with the company have a fifth go at it?

You are probably better off out of there.

Answer (score 5):

Were you a replacement for someone who left the company?

This sounds like they were trying to recover from the [bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor).

I suspect there was nothing you could do. The previous guy took all the knowledge with him. There was no training because they didn't have any, and they gave you the keys to production because no one else knows how it works.

You had problems because you're not the other guy. They didn't know what to do so they fired you.

I wouldn't think more about it. They will suffer the costs of their mistakes over time. You'll hopefully find another job. Let this experience be a warning you can share with your future employers about the costs associated with the bus factory.

Answer (score 4):

With 10 years of experience they expected you to hit the ground running and give error free work. Which you failed to do. So yes, you didn't meet their expectations during your probation and they were within reason to let you go.

It's what probation is for. Most places they can terminate you for any reason, but in this case it's pretty clear you consistently failed to deliver, so keeping you on would be bad for business. There isn't much worse than impacting production and interrupting the normal workflow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79120/discussion-on-answer-by-kilisi-terminated-for-too-many-mistakes-on-the-first-mon).